# Dynamic routing based on file system directory search

Tags: node.js, express

I want to route to an HTML page without having '.html' in the URL.  I am trying to do this by creating a custom router that looks through a directory and checks to see if there is a file with the extension '.html', if there is it will route to that page.

I also need to allow the router to fall through the `'/api'` route if the URL contains '/api'.  Essentially I want to allow users to get HTML files without having to type the file extension and keep all other routing intact.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

router.route('/:id')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        fs.readdir('public/', function(err, items) {
            for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
              if (req.params.id == path.basename(items[i])) {
                app.get(function(req, res) {
                    res.render(items[i]);
                });
            }
          }
        });
    });

router.route('/api')
  .get(function (req, res) { ... })
  .post(function (req, res) { ... });

app.use('/', router);
```

I also tried using `express.static` but its not working either.

`fs.readdir('public/', function(err, items) {
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        if (path.extname(items[i]) == '.html') {
            app.use('/' + path.basename(items[i], '.html'), express.static(items[i]));
        }
    }
});`

Comment: Have you looked at [`express.static`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static)? To serve html pages dependent on url you can do `app.use('/some-url', express.static('path/to/file.html')`

Comment: I need the `'/some-url'` part to be dynamic because html files will be getting added and removed.